# How do I change the text color in Pinta?

Tags: 18.04, image-processing, pinta

I'm using [Pinta](https://pinta-project.com/pintaproject/pinta/) in Ubuntu and have added a text box to my image. I then added text, which doesn't show because, I assume, it's white colored. I can highlight the text and see the length is correct, but can't see the actual text. I have tried changing the primary and secondary palette to multiple different colors, including having both solid black, tried setting the text width number to maximum, changing the text 'style', bold, different fonts and sizes, tried googling, watched a few "getting started" YouTube videos and now I have to make a legit forum post...

Comment: This problem is not reproducible in my Pinta in 18.04 which sometimes doesn't load correctly, so this problem may be attributable to a bug.

Comment: please also include data on your system. What desktop environment are you using, etc and if you have installed any custom themes.

Answer (score 0):

If the text is plain white, select all of the text with the *Rectangle Select* tool, hover your mouse over the *Adjustments* tab and then click the *Invert colors* button. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty late to the party, but I've had the same issue and it's been driving me mad - it appears to be a selection bug.  if you deselect everything before placing the text box then it obeys the color selection.